# java - register parent JPanel to MouseEvent

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouseevent, jscrollpane

Consider I have the following code:

```
public LSUIEditingPanel(LSView view) {
    super();
    parent     = view;
    controller = view.getController();

    LayoutManager overlay = new OverlayLayout(this);

    setLayout(overlay);
    scribbleArea = new LSScribblePanel();
    scribbleArea.setOpaque(false);
    add(scribbleArea);
    viewArea = new LSCanvasViewport(view);
    add(viewArea);
    setAutoscrolls(true);
    drawListener = new SVGEditorDrawMouseAdaptor();

}
```

where scribbleArea and viewArea are both a custom JPanel. They are both subpanels added to the main panel.

Now I want do make it such that I can register a MouseEvent to the parent panel itself, which is I could do a panning of the panel as the parent panel will be embed in a JScrollPane after instantiating.

This is the code segment performing the dragging:

```
public class LSPanMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {

/**
 * Panning pivot point
 */
private final Point panPoint = new Point();

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}<p>
 * Set pan starting point to be the point where the mouse currently located, and change the
 * current cursor to <code>HAND_CURSOR</code>.
 */
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
    JViewport  viewport  = (JViewport) event.getSource();
    JComponent component = (JComponent) viewport.getView();

    panPoint.setLocation(event.getPoint());
    component.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}<p>
 * Reset cursor to <code>DEFAULT_CURSOR</code>.
 */
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
    JViewport  viewport  = (JViewport) event.getSource();
    JComponent component = (JComponent) viewport.getView();

    component.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}<p>
 * Get the current viewport of the canvas and move the viewable area respective to the
 * event cursor location.
 */
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
    JViewport  viewport     = (JViewport) event.getSource();
    JComponent component    = (JComponent) viewport.getView();
    Point      currentPoint = event.getPoint();
    Point      viewPoint    = viewport.getViewPosition();

    viewPoint.translate(panPoint.x - currentPoint.x, panPoint.y - currentPoint.y);
    component.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(viewPoint, viewport.getSize()));
    panPoint.setLocation(currentPoint);
}
}
```

I have tried registering the event but the parent panel does not fire the event, any suggestion on how should I do this?

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you're adding the MouseListener to the parent panel, such that the event callbacks will be called. Also won't the child panels receive mouse events, since they are in front of the parent? (I can't remember whether they propagate to underlying components.)

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, still no idea why is there JViewport and with scrollRectToVisible and DragAndDrop???, no battery in my mind_readers cells, before anything maybe to check SwingUtilities#convert...

Comment: @mKorbel Sorry for the lengthy code, but thanks for your reminder on convertMouseEvent =)

Answer (score 2):

See this example below which shows how you can have some kind of view port drag. The mouse listener is attached to the viewport view and modifies the viewport position as the mouse is dragged. In order to compute proper "offset" of the mouse, mouse locations are converted into viewport coordinates as the mouse is dragged.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestDragViewPortView {
    public static class MouseDragger extends MouseAdapter {
        private Point startPoint;
        private Component draggedObject;
        private JViewport viewport;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            draggedObject = (Component) e.getSource();
            viewport = (JViewport) SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JViewport.class, draggedObject);
            if (viewport != null) {
                startPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(draggedObject, e.getPoint(), viewport);
                draggedObject.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (viewport == null) {
                return;
            }
            Point location = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(draggedObject, e.getPoint(), viewport);
            Point newPosition = viewport.getViewPosition();
            newPosition.translate(startPoint.x - location.x, startPoint.y - location.y);
            newPosition.x = Math.min(newPosition.x, draggedObject.getWidth() - viewport.getExtentSize().width);
            newPosition.y = Math.min(newPosition.y, draggedObject.getHeight() - viewport.getExtentSize().height);
            newPosition.x = Math.max(newPosition.x, 0);
            newPosition.y = Math.max(newPosition.y, 0);
            viewport.setViewPosition(newPosition);
            startPoint = location;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            draggedObject.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
            startPoint = null;
            draggedObject = null;
            viewport = null;
        }

        public void makeDraggable(Component component) {
            component.addMouseListener(this);
            component.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        }

    }

    private JFrame frame;

    protected void initUI() throws MalformedURLException {
        frame = new JFrame(TestDragViewPortView.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL("http://blogs.dirteam.com/photos/sanderberkouwer/images/2157/original.aspx")));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(background);
        new MouseDragger().makeDraggable(background);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(frame.getWidth() / 2, frame.getHeight() / 2);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new TestDragViewPortView().initUI();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I was struggling 3 days with something, which manifested itself as a innocent visual glitch. I tried glass panes, JLayer, subclassing JViewport and event retargeting. Still I don't know what is my problem - I suspected a drag event was created when the viewport moved component under the mouse - and here, Your code worked straight out of the box. I guess that the coordinate changing part is crucial.